# Inserting values from a report to a database

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm having Crystal Reports (on-demand sub report) write some pre-set test values (like 1,2,3,4,5,6) in to a different database with the help of a database procedure, that inserts the pre-set values and returns a dummy value to Crystal Reports.

The sql command looks like this:
CALL TestProcedure(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Now, the only thing left is to replace the dummy values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 with values provided by Crystal Reports.

Here's an example what I'm after:
CALL TestProcedure({@CustomerName},{@CustomerPhoneNumber},{@CustomerAddress},{@CustomerPostCode},{@OrderDate},{@TotalSumOfTheOrder})

Because I'm fairly new to Crystal Reports, I'll provide some additional information from here onwards to help understand what I'm trying to accomplish here a little bit better:
Our waybills are reports that get addresses, names and delivery company's names etc. etc. from the database (1 report per customer).
I need to have the report write most of the data from the waybill report into a different database for further processing.

Is there any way of getting a field value and inserting it in to the sql command?

Comment: This approach seems very misguided. The Crystal Reports reporting framework is designed for reading and displaying data from a database, not writing to it. It sounds like what you really want is to replicate the data between the two databases, then use the output of that to run your report, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add parameters to the sql command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the proper way to do it, but you can make some TextLabels and via Crystal Reports designer to set the value of a field. There is a c# code which can help you getting the value of that TextLabel if you made an instance of your Crystal Report in your code.